# Laravel web routing order

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am creating a storage app with laravel, and I'm working on the pages displaying the files. In my controller, there is one function to load files where deleted="no" to the home page, and another function to load files that where deleted="yes" to the bin page. However, the bin page refuses to load

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
Route::get('get/{files}', 'RoofController@getFile')->name('getfile');
Route::name('roofs_path')->get('/home', 'RoofController@index');
Route::name('store_roof_path')->post('/home', 'RoofController@store');
Route::name('deletefile')->get('{fileToDelete}', 'RoofController@deleteFile');
});

//route to files not deleted
Route::name('index')->get('/home', 'RoofController@index')->middleware('verified');
//route to files deleted
Route::name('bin')->get('/home', 'RoofController@bin')->middleware('verified');
```

And the bin function in the controller

```
   public function index()
    {   
        //get id and name of user
        $id = Auth::id();
        //specify 'where' array...get only non-deleted files and user's files
        $files_to_get = ['user_id' => $id, 'deleted' => 'no'];

        //get all files into an array
        $all_files = File::where($files_to_get)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

    //print_r($all_files);

    return view('home', [
        'files' => $all_files
    ]);


}

public function bin()
{   
    //get id and name of user
    $id = Auth::id();
    //specify 'where' array...get only non-deleted files and user's files
    $files_to_get = ['user_id' => $id, 'deleted' => 'yes'];

    //get all files into an array
    $all_files = File::where($files_to_get)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

    //print_r($all_files);

    return view('bin', [
        'files' => $all_files
    ]);


}
```

Comment: Laravel selects which controller/method to load at the route phase, at this point it has no idea what the difference between `/home -> @index` and `/home -> @bin` is, because it hasn't loaded the method associated with the route until it is selected.  Add a `deleted` parameter to the bin route and use that rather than a GET var.

Comment: I tried this but the link to the bin file still doesn't work. Here is the link in the view: 
<button href="{{route('bin')}}">Bin</button>...and could you five an example of the deleted parameter?

Comment: The problem you have is that you have 2 routes with the same URL, what you name a route is irrelevant (it's actually just for convenience), the system matches URLs not route names. Change the URL for the bin route.

Comment: Ok I've changed that to:                                                                  
Route::name('bin')->get('/bin', 'RoofController@bin')->middleware('verified')....but the bin.blade still isn't loading

Comment: So you need to do some debugging then, `dd()` in the bin method.

Comment: are you using model soft delete for File model?

Comment: No I am not using soft delete. I am actually just learning Laravel so the routing is a bit new to me